# Browser automatically adds spacing to <input> elements, how can I remove them?

Tags: html, css

Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/JPQxX/

I tried this in Chrome and FF. In both browsers there's a 1-2px margin between the two inputs. I want to make the two elements touch without explicitly shifting the submit button to the left. Margin is already set to 0px;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reset the `border` style and it should work http://jsfiddle.net/JPQxX/1/

```
input { border: 1px solid grey; }
```

Comment: This also changes the entire appearance of the submit button.

Answer (score 0):

The elements do touch, without a margin. If you inspect the submit button element in Firebug, you’ll see that it has no margin but a border that is 3px wide. What seems to be a small margin is part of the border. If you take a screen capture and magnify, you can see that the border has a 1px wide gray part with 1px wide transparent parts on each side of it, except at the rounded corners.

The default border is drawn by built-in routines in browsers, and modern browsers tend to use this kind of routines. If you set border properties for the button in CSS, browsers tend to switch to normal border drawing, so the button stops looking like a normal button and takes whatever shape you set. I don’t think you can completely simulate the default border appearance (getting rid just of the transparent part that causes the margin-like phenomenon), but the following might take you sufficiently close (on supporting browsers):

```
input[type="submit"] {
    border: solid gray 1px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    background: #ddd;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/m2CSy/